# Angular How to put elementRef of child component into itself?

Tags: angular, nested, viewchild, elementref

I have a parent component, with a child component.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
    styleUrl: './parent.component.scss'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder = inject(FormBuilder);
  parentForm: FormGroup;
  @ViewChild('checkListRef', { read: ElementRef, static: true }) elementRef: ElementRef; 

 ngOnInit() {
    this.parentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      child: this.formBuilder.control( [] )
    });
 }
}
```

The Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="parentForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(parentForm)" novalidate autocomplete="off">
  <app-child #childRef [elementRef]="elementRef">
  </app-child>
</form>
```

The Child component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
    styleUrl: './child.component.scss'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
 private formBuilder: FormBuilder = inject(FormBuilder);
 childForm: FormGroup;
 @Input() elementRef: ElementRef;
 
 ngOnInit() {
    this.childForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      ...
    });
 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
  // at this point I would like to use the elementRef but it some cases undefined
  console.log(this.elementRef);
 }
 
}
```

The Child component template:

```
<form [formGroup]="childForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(childForm)" novalidate autocomplete="off">
  ...
</form>
```

My problem is, some cases when the parent component did a lot of thing in the ngOnInit(), in the child component lifecycle hook AfterViewInit the this.elementRef remains undefined because processing the child component first and the elementRef did not get valuable elementRef in time.

How can I avoid this? I need the real elementRef.

Comment: `elementRef` is a input of the `ChildComponent `  so I think you should use `ngOnChange` instead  `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz of your code and explain the functionality you'd like to achieve because  I see quite a few problems with your code.  One problem is in the `@ViewChild` you're using the id `checkListRef` while in your template you're using the id `#childRef` which will cause an `undefined` error because the `@ViewChild` can't find an element with the name `checkListRef`.  You can also use the component recursively within itself by adding `<app-child>` in the template so I don't understand why you're trying to pass it into itself through an `@Input()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the elementRef directly when you're in a component:

```
elementRef = inject(ElementRef)
```